# Business logic in composable or in pinia action?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, pinia, nuxt3

I have a composable `useAuth` that deals with authentification. If successful, I want to save the current user in my store.

**Should the business logic happen in this composable**, which in turn calls an action of my store "setUser", **or should the whole action deal with it?** What do I need my composable for then?

Also, do I really need a dedicated action "setUser" to mutate the state, or could I mutate it directly? Opinions about this vary online ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need a dedicated action "setUser" to change the state, or you can change it directly.

use like that type of your Business logic structure.

useAuth.js

```
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useStore } from 'pinia';

export function useAuth() {
  const store = useStore();
  const isAuthenticated = ref(false);

  async function login(username, password) {
    // Perform authentication logic here (e.g., API request).
    // If authentication is successful, set isAuthenticated to true.
    // You can also retrieve user data at this point.

    isAuthenticated.value = true;
    
    // Call the store action to set the user in the global state.
    store.setUser({ username, /* other user data */ });
  }

  function logout() {
    isAuthenticated.value = false;
    // Clear user data in the store if necessary.
    store.clearUser();
  }

  return {
    isAuthenticated,
    login,
    logout,
  };
}
```

store.js

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useAuthStore = defineStore('auth', {
  state: () => ({
    user: null,
  }),

  actions: {
    setUser(user) {
      // Use an action to set the user in the store's state.
      this.user = user;
    },

    clearUser() {
      // Use an action to clear the user from the store's state.
      this.user = null;
    },
  },
});
```

LoginComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="login">Login</button>
    <button @click="logout">Logout</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { useAuth } from './useAuth';

export default {
  setup() {
    const { isAuthenticated, login, logout } = useAuth();

    return {
      isAuthenticated,
      login,
      logout,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I hope it work for your requirement Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am afraid you are missing the point. I know how to implement this but I was asking about shifting the business logic entirely to an action (that would perform the login and mutate the sate). 

Both solutions technically work, I am just not sure which one to prefer and why 

Comment: Sorry, now I understand a question.
Your choice should be based on the specific needs of your application. Placing your authentication method in a composable may be sufficient if it is directly and closely tied to a particular component.

However, if your application expands or if you anticipate more complex authentication logic in the future, using a dedicated action to  mutate the state is a cleaner and more maintainable way.

But, I use it and recommend using it mutate the state directly.